# Read java keystore password from file

Tags: java, security, passwords, keystore, jsse

I'm using VM-Args to configure a keystore in Java:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=myJks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret
```

The problem is that the password is not allowed to be visible in the arguments of this java call (my client's requirement). Is there any way how I can define the parameters in a seperate file?
Like -Xoptionsfile= in IBM JVM...

Comment: Just stick it in a .prooerties file and set this system property from code after reading it.

Comment: Best way would be to not change the code and keep the ssl logic out of the program...

Comment: You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) mentioned, it seems that there is no way to do this.